# Programa de loteria

Tags: python

Buenas noches estoy comenzando mis andadas con python (soy principiante), estoy desarrollando un script para un progama de lotería, pero no para generar los números aleatoriamente sino con algunas fuciones.

Primero extraigo con parsefeed los siete últimos sorteos, analizo los números repetidos, la media aritmética de cada sorteo, los que han salido una vez en siete sorteos, los que no han salido, etc.

En base a esto elijo una combinación de números probables y genero todas las combinaciones posibles:

```py
    def generador():
        a = [1, 4, 7, 12, 15, 21, 23]
        combinations = list(itertools.permutations(a, 6))
        a = str(combinations)
        return a
```

Ahora bien, no sé cómo aplicar algunas de las condiciones que quiero implementar:

1. Me gustaría seleccionar todas aquellas combinaciones dentro de un rango de la media aritmética. He utilizado el módulo stats.mean(combinacion()) para generar la media aritmética de las combinaciones individualmente pero dada la lista que me genera la función permutation(), ¿Cómo podría hacer para seleccionar sólo aquellas combinaciones que estén dentro de un rango de media aritmética (por ejemplo 20)?, e.g.: La combinación 5,7,12,26,29,41 cumpliría la condición porque su media aritmética es 20, el resto de combinaciones que no la cumplen se descartarían.
2. Quiero seleccionar sólo aquellas combinaciones cuya diferencia entre número sea de 1 o 2. ¿Cómo podría hacerlo? e.g.: La combinación 1,25,28,31,40,49 no presenta diferencias entre alguno de sus números de 1 o 2, por lo tanto se descartaría. La combinación 1,3,14,34,37,40 presenta una diferencia de 2 entre el 1 y el 3, por lo que sería seleccionada. La combinación 2,14,16,25,30,45 presenta una diferencia de 2 entre el número 14 y 16, por lo tanto sería seleccionada.
3. Seleccionar sólo aquellas combinaciones que presenten uno o dos números contiguos, e.g.: La combinación 2,15,16,26,29,34 contiene al 15 y al 16 que son números contiguos, por lo tanto sería seleccionada. La combinación 2,15,23,27,30,34 no presenta números contiguos, por lo tanto no sería seleccionada.

Muchas gracias,

Un saludo.

Comment: Generar en memoria todas las combinaciones e ir descartándolas en un bucle según una serie de condiciones, aunque parezca mentira es demasiado lento. Yo probaría a hacerlo apoyándome con alguna libreria como Pandas ( https://pandas.pydata.org/ o aquí https://aprendeconalf.es/docencia/python/manual/pandas/ ) que proporciona una estructura de datos de matriz y tienen algunos beneficios respecto a las listas de Python. Seguro que con eso podrás manejar conjuntos de datos para ir descartando o no las combinaciones. Eso sí, cuando lo consigas deja por aquí algún mensaje. XDDD

Comment: El concepto central de la lotería es que sea aleatoria. Si pones reglas, deja de ser aleatoria y el resultado se torna predecible. Alguien astuto puede usar este conocimiento para inclinar los resultados a su favor.

Comment: Como te han dicho, generar la lista con todas las combinaciones en memoria no es la mejor opción, pero no por la lentitud, sino por lo que ocuparía innecesariamente si al final vas a descartar muchas. Pandas no ayudaría en este caso. Lo que debes hacer es iterar por los resultados que va devolviendo `permutations()` y ver si cumplen la condición que buscas para meterlos en la lista resultado. Esto ahorra memoria porque `permutations()` no crea listas sino que va generando las combinaciones una a una

Answer (score 6):

Tu enfoque tiene importantes problemas de consumo excesivo de memoria. Primero, la cantidad de permutaciones que se pueden llegar a generar crece de forma desorbitada a medida que tienes más números "elegibles". Y el problema aparece en que tú usas `list()` para convertir en una lista todas las permutaciones halladas.

Esto es muy ineficiente ya que muchas de esas combinaciones las vas a descartar luego, por lo que no tiene sentido consumir toda esa memoria guardando combinaciones que no vas a querer al final.

Por si fuera poco, después vuelves a convertir la lista completa en una cadena, usando `str()`. No veo el sentido de hacer esto, ya que la función podría retornar directamente la lista. Convertirlo a cadena va a llevar mucho tiempo y va a requerir otra vez mucha memoria.

Pero es que ni siquiera necesitas retornar la lista con los resultados si usas un enfoque basado en *generadores*. Estas son funciones que en lugar de `return` contienen `yield` y en vez de retornar listas, "retornan" (con `yield`) los elementos de uno en uno.

Basándose en esta idea podrías hacer una función que:

- Llame a `itertools.permutations()` para generar todas las permutaciones *una a una* (sin convertirlas en una lista)
- Cada permutación generada se mira si pasa o no cada uno de tus test (puedes tener funciones aparte que implementen esos test)
- Si algún test falla, se pasa a la siguiente combinación (usando `continue`)
- Sólo si todos los test han pasado, se "retorna" (con `yield`) esa combinación.

Esta sería la implementación (aunque faltan las funciones que hacen los test):

```
def generador(elegibles):
    for combinacion in itertools.permutations(elegibles, 6):
       if not promedio_es(combinacion, 20):
          continue
       if not presenta_saltos(combinacion):
          continue
       if not hay_dos_seguidos(combinacion):
          continue

       # Si pasa todos los test, la retornamos
       yield combinacion
```

Las funciones que faltan recibirían una sola combinación y retornarían `True` si pasan el test correspondiente. Por ejemplo, la más simple, sería así:

```
def promedio_es(combinacion, valor):
   return (sum(combinacion)/len(combinacion) == valor)
```

De momento te dejo que pienses cómo podrían implementarse el resto de las condiciones. Pregunta de nuevo si te atascas.

Una vez los test estuvieran implementados, lo que tendríamos sería un generador que se puede usar en un bucle, por ejemplo para mostrar todas las combinaciones que hayan pasado los test, así:

```
a = [1, 4, 7, 12, 15, 21, 23]
for numeros in generador(a):
   print(numeros)
```

Si quieres también puedes crear una lista con los resultados:

```
todas_las_validas = list(generador(a))
```

por si luego quieres usar algún mecanismo para extraer una de esas combinaciones de la lista. No obstante, en lo posible, evita crear esta lista si no vas a necesitar todos sus elementos, para evitar consumo innecesario de memoria.

Answer (score 1):

Una forma de evitar pasar una lista de números que hacen tu algoritmo predecible es generar los números de forma aleatoria.

Te dejo un código de apoyo de como hacerlo:

```
import secrets, string

def NumeroAleatorio(digitos):
    "Genera numeros aleatorios del tamaño indicado"
    return "".join(secrets.choice(string.digits) for i in range(digitos))

# Generacion de 10 numeros de 2 digitos aleatorios
numeros = [NumeroAleatorio(2) for i in range(10)]
```